# 'transform': is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Here is my code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // su is the string which is converted to lowercase
    std::wstring su = L"HeLLo WoRld";

    // using transform() function and ::toupper in STL
    std::transform(su.begin(), su.end(), su.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::cout << su << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It generates the following compilation error.

```
1>c:\users\root\source\repos\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp(14): error C2039: 'transform': is not a member of 'std'
1>c:\users\root\source\repos\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp(14): error C3861: 'transform': identifier not found
1>c:\users\root\source\repos\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp(15): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::wstring' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    3 Error(s)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `std::transform` is declared in header `<algorithm>`, which you need to `#include`

Comment: use `std::wcout` for a `std::wstring`

Comment: Also, for the sake of const correctness, use cbegin() and cend() wherever possible (and appropriate)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to include the  header.

Add:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: also use **using namespace std;** or **std::transform**

Comment: I also ran into this problem for `std::ranges::transform` - which _isn't_ defined in the `ranges` header, but rather also in the `algorithm` header